# Write code in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I have below lines of code and I want to add it in my beamer presentation. I tried below mentioned approach but it failed. The requirement is that it should also show line number.

```
1. int main(){
2. printf("hello");
3. return 0;

}
```

I Used this:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \semiverbatim{
            1. int main(){
            2. printf("hello");
            3. return 0;
   
    } 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: also "it failed" is not anything that anyone can debug, If you got an error show the exact error message that you got, copied from the log filre as text.

Comment: One common issue is that you need to make a frame fragile in order to include any verbatim content such as listings, i.e., `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Comment: When you say 'I tried the below mentioned approach', do you mean the answer by tobiasBora? If so, then how exactly did it fail? From his screenshot you can see that it works for him, what is different for you? Or did you mean you tried my comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `\begin{frame}[fragile]` environment, for line numbering you can use the `listings` package, it has numerous options, for line numbering it is `numbers=left`. You can also use `\lstinputlisting{yourfile.c}` to input directly a C file, and `lstautogobble` is useful to remove indentation based on the first line. For more options (colors…) to typeset C code, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348651/c-code-to-add-in-the-document/348653), I provided a very simple example. Btw, next time provide a full (i.e. compilable) minimal working example like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble} % Provides autogobble, which is useful to remove indentation based on first line

\lstset{ %
  language=C,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  autogobble=true, % Removes indentation based on first line
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \begin{lstlisting}
        int main(){
          printf("hello");
          return 0;
        }
      \end{lstlisting}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks good but numbers on left is not coming

Comment: @shyam Really? That's strange. Maybe try to compile several times. Also, I tried to add a few more options, I'm not sure if it will change something but you can try. If it's not enough, you can edit your answer with a screenshot of what you obtain, and the code you use (it should be basically a copy/paste of what I sent).

Comment: Yeah now it came. But i want to align to center.

Comment: @shyam Then a quick research would point you to this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing : wrap your code inside `\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c} ... \end{tabular}\end{center}`,

Comment: I edited the code to automatically remove indentation based on first line (otherwise your code is shifted to the right)

Comment: Thanks I understood it.